# Why IQueryable shows all the time in Contains function "false" even this should be true

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, collections, iqueryable

I've got a problem with my Iqueryable cuz. When i get an items with hours (array in console log shows Array [ "08:00", "08:00", "08:30"] and when I put some code

```
var test = visits.AsQueryable().Contains("08:30");
```

Like this then shows me false, everytime, any solutions for this problem?

Bellow list with visits

```
var visits = _context.Visits.Where(a => a.Date.Date.ToString() == date).Where(a=>a.Doctor.Id == idDoc).Select(a=>a.Date.ToShortTimeString());
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: How do you output values to console?

Comment: With jsonresult in controller, then put console.log(data) in ajax function on success

Comment: Could you please show the Visits model make up?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the string returned by the ToShortTimeString method is culture-sensitive.

It reflects the pattern defined by the current culture's DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortTimePattern property.

For example, for the en-US culture, the standard short time pattern is "h:mm tt"; for the de-DE culture, it is "HH:mm"; for the ja-JP culture, it is "H:mm".

Note that its value can vary depending on the .NET implementation and its version, the operating system and its version, and user customization.

If your sever is en-US culture, the returned value will be `8:30 AM` format. So I suggest you could try to use `var test = visits.AsQueryable().Contains("8:30");` instead of `visits.AsQueryable().Contains("08:30");`.

All the result should based on your culture.